Article use with countables used in a "concept sense"
I know that as a general rule, countable singular nouns need an article in English, but I'm uncertain about cases where the noun is used non-referentially, rather than to refer to an actual referent. For instance, consider the following examples:

Decisions regarding a/the/0 chairperson for the meeting... (meaning decisions as to who should serve as the chairperson)
Discussions about a/the/0 date for the ceremony...
Who should be a/the/0 compere?

Which is the correct alternative in these examples? Is there a rule here, or does it differ from one situation to another?

My instinctive answer is that there's no difference between a noun and the idea of what a noun means. Is that not the purpose of a noun anyway? As to your examples... (1) a or the both work in context. Ditto for (2). In (3) all of the options work in the right setting.

@PeterKirkpatrick Thanks! What I meant was that a noun is normally used to refer to a referent, right? But in some cases it isn't... I've edited my OP, so hopefully it's clearer now :) Anyway, just so I get it right, you're saying that there has to be an article in 1 and 2, but that 3 works without an article?

In the bad old days it was quite common to have discussions regarding [the] chairmanship of the meeting, but it would have to be ... chairpersonship of the meeting now.  In that exact context it's just a stylistic choice whether to precede it by the definite article. But it wouldn't be idiomatic to include an indefinite article (a) before the -ship form (it's okay with a chairperson, though).

@FumbleFingers Excellent!Thanks!

@Helen - Yes, but note that the precise form and context is really important. For example, "We had discussions regarding the/a chairman for the meeting" would be wrong without the article. But "We discussed who should be [the] chairman..." is fine with or without the article.

I think it's a fairly subtle point why you can't naturally refer to discussions about a chairpersonship of the meeting, but you can have  discussions about a chairperson of the meeting. It's because until the actual chairperson is decided on, there are several potential "chairpeople" (Jeez, how I hate politically-correct vocabulary! :). But there's only ever one chairpersonship, before and after the specific person is chosen for the position.

Thank you both for your input – I'm starting to realise why I find this difficult, haha XD
